# Is socket.io or websocket safe to use with an express server?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, real-time-updates

I was wondering to have a realtime system made with express and i came to know about socket.io and websockets. But the way they are used i.e.
`const io = socket.io("https://example.com") ;`

Is it safe to use. Since the url for socket connection is available at client side any third party service can enjoy and exploit the services by connecting from their service. I don't have much idea about socket.io so correct me if I am wrong.

Kindly don't mark this question as duplicate since I found a similar question but the answer to it was related to game development, here I am specific about updating clients whenever any updates are there on the server side. Clients may be website made with angular or apps made with Android studio.
Any help is highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

socket.io is widely used. It is perfectly fine for use in production.

Regarding the authentication part, A websocket connection b/w client and browser is established via http upgrade request(in http/1.1).
If you have an authentication mechanism in place for your application using cookie and session then you should be safe. No one can establish websocket connection directly without first logging in. On top of this you can limit connection per user to ensure that a registered user cant further exploit the connection using the cookie data.

Comment: Is it feasible to use socket connection(bidirectional communication) because in my case the server needs to send data when any changes take place in database. What about SSE(SERVER SENT EVENTS) OR SOMETHING LIKE THAT?

Comment: SSE is plain http whereas websocket is a different protocol which uses http for handshake only. I would suggest to use websockets over alternatives like SSE or long polling. Also note that SSE cant handle binary data and will use up one dedicated connection b/w the server and browser which can be an issue because browsers limit connections(6-10) to a domain across tabs. In case of websockets this limit is much higher. However websockets can get a bit complicated if your web app needs to be highly scalable. But in most cases websockets will work flawlessly.

Comment: You can also consider polling if timely updates on client side is not very crucial. Ex: A lot of stock and crypto ticker dashboard use polling or websockets.

Comment: can you share any possible examples which explains how can we authenticate socket io connection with mean stack. Any resource (link, video) will also be of great help